# How to bring Twitter Tweet with Twitter Card to work?

Tags: asp.net-core, twitter, cors

I try to implement a Twitter Tweet button on my web page (asp.net core console app) with Twitter Card.
Goal: submit link to my web page, title, description and image (over the twitter meta tags) with the tweet (see image below).

All meta tags are filled correct on my web page (the target page).
If I paste the link to my web page in this tool:
http://debug.iframely.com/?uri=<link_to_my_webpage>

**Anything is showed correct (title, description and image):**
[image]

If I use the **Twitter Card Validator**:
https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

I see an error message in card validator:
"ERROR: Failed to fetch page due to: HttpConnectionTimeout"

If I load the browser debugger (all browsers), I see that some resources were blocked by CORS
**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'**

[image: Error Messages Google Chrome]

**Details:**
Access to font at '**[https://ton.twimg.com/tfw/fonts/rosetta-icons-Regular.woff**'](https://ton.twimg.com/tfw/fonts/rosetta-icons-Regular.woff**%27) from origin '**https://cards-dev.twitter.com**' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

So.. both urls are **twitter internal urls (not my site)**.
I assume, that the twitter tweet interface has the same problems and this is the reason that it does not work...
If I use the 3-th party tool (iframely, see link above), it works as expected, so it seems as the implementation of the metatags on my website is o.k..

Note: I already have implemented a FB share button (with the FB meta tags) on the same web page, that works without problems.

**Thanks for any help (what can cause this problem and how to solve it).**

**Update to the solution:**

- **It WAS the Port - see my comments to the accepted answer.**
- **I still see the errors above in GC debugger, but this do not cause the problems.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you able to have your site at a URL that does not include an explicit port number? I think you may find that the Twitter Cards Validator does not like having a port number in the domain.

Comment: First, thanks for your posting. No, as another app (old version) is running in parallel. By the migration, the port will be removed. As I wrote the iframly tool and also FB have no problems. Are you SURE, that Twitter really has a problem with the port (I'm able to post only the link to Twitter from the app, but the metas are not used)?

Comment: It is a very high probability, but I cannot be 100% sure. I wrote the main [troubleshooting guide for Twitter Cards](https://twittercommunity.com/t/card-error-unable-to-render-or-no-image-read-this-first/62736) and the only other thing I can think of is the explicit port, or an SSL issue. Or, very possibly, the Twitterbot crawler being blocked somehow.

Comment: Thanks again. In the meantime, I was able to remove the port (as the old app runs on http and the new on https), but now, I have another problem (also with the FB interface). The app is running (without the port) in the browser without any problem (show valid cert), but in card validator I now have "ERROR: Fetching the page failed because other errors". and FB sharing debugger says "Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid." although its a valid (pubic an bought) cert, that works in the browser

Comment: Yes this is an SSL certificate chain issue.

Comment: It seems as our watchguard firewall give back the internal (self signed watchguard cert) now (after I have removed the port) for whatever reason, but only for non browser calls (in the browser, anything works correct and the browser shows a valid cert). Very strange - I'm in contact with a watchguard specialist now to try solve the issue.

Comment: Conclusion: Andy Piper was right - it WAS the port. Facebook have no problem with a port, but Twitter (for whatever reason). After fix the problems on our watchguard FW, it works now also with Twitter - BUT ONLY WITHOUT PORT.